# remove formula links in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am copying worksheet from book1 to book2.  The worksheet contains cells with formulas.  On worksheet 'sheet1' in book2 the cell contains a link back to `book1.sheet1  ='Y:\temp\\[book1.xls]sheet1'!A1`

My question is how to I strip out the `Y:\temp\\[book1.xls]sheet1` and just have `sheet1!A1` ?  Basically making book2 the source.

I have tried:

```
        for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfSheets; i++)
        {

            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wbDestination.Sheets[i];

            Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;
            bool success = (bool)r.Replace(
                @"'Y:\temp\[book1.xls]sheet1'",
                "Sheet1",
                XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                false, m, m, m);
        }
```

This doesn't work and get a message that excel was unable to find any matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for my needs.  I hope it helps someone out. I used the following code.

```
        Array links = wbOut.LinkSources(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks) as Array;
        if (links != null)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= links.Length; i++)
            {

                wbOut.ChangeLink(@"c:\temp\book1.xls", @"c:\temp\book2.xls", 
                       XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a verbatim string:

```
@"'Y:\temp\[book1.xls]sheet1'"
```

instead of

```
"'Y:\temp\[book1.xls]sheet1'"
```

In a verbatim string, all those special characters are interpreted literally.

Comment: That causes an "Unrecognized escape sequence".  I have also tried:

Comment: "'Y:\\temp\\[book1.xls]sheet1'" with no luck.

Comment: What is if you try "\'Y:\\temp\\\[book1.xls]sheet1\'" instead? That means, escaping all special characters with a backslash?

Comment: Nebr, I changed it as suggested and same outcome as using the @ before.  finding no matches.  And I have verified that string does exist in the sheets.  Even going as far as copy and pasting directly into the code.

Comment: Might it be because the cell is a formula and not a text cell?

Comment: Maybe, but I rather assume that it has something to do with the representation of the '. Does the replacement work if you omit the '-characters? If it is because of being a formula, you can also try to use .Formula.Replace instead of .Replace. But I have to admit that this is just guessing at this point.